# Is there any way to autorelease topics in ActiveMQ broker

Tags: activemq-classic

in web console, it seems that AMQ remembers what topics have been used even consumer is 0 for a long time. I think it keeps the thread for the topic active. Is there any way to configure it to release topics after some duration or anything familiar? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can configure ActiveMQ Broker to have a policy to delete inactive queues or topics. See details at this page: http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html